# When each one of A, B, C and D is present

Tags: word-choice

I want to describe "capacitance between a pair of electrodes when A is present", "capacitance between a pair of electrodes when B is present", "capacitance between a pair of electrode when C is present, and "capacitance between a pair of electrodes when D is present", collectively. 
Can I say "capacitance between a pair of electrodes when each one of A, B, C, and D are present" ?
It seems to me that this sentence means "capacitance between a pair of electrodes when all of A, B, C and D are present".
Is it possible to say "-- when A, B, C and D are respectively present" ? or "-- when respective ones of A, B, C and D are present" ?
Please teach me how to describe this situation.

Comment: Hello, Rie.The version "capacitance between a pair of electrodes when X is present (X being exactly one of A, B, C and D)" wouldn't win a prize for style, but then few science articles would.

Comment: The problem is simply OP's misuse of ***each***. There's no significant ambiguity in *...when **any** one of A, B, C, and D are [**is**] present*.

Comment: Mr. Ashworth, what is the correct phrase of "capacitance between a pair of electrodes when X is present" ?

Comment: Mr.FumbleFingers, I need to mention differences between capacitance values between when A is present, when B is present, when C is present and when D is present. Therefore, I have to say "any one of A, B, C, and D" is not the phrase I want.

Comment: The Question did not mention differences.  Does the capacitance depend on which one of the four (A,B,C,D) is present (which would make sense?)  Are A, B, C, D different dielectrics?

Comment: Mr.Ab2,  thank you for your comment. The capacitance depends on which one of the four is present between a pair of electrodes. For example, A is water, B is methanol, C is ethanol, and D is blood.  A, B, C and D have different dieletric constances.

Comment: @Rie Tanaka You have answered your own question in your comment above:: "The capacitance depends on which one of the four (A, B, C, or D) is present between a pair of electrodes."

Comment: Sorry, but we can't tell you how to describe it until you describe it, which you have not yet done.

Answer (score 0):

> capacitance between a pair of electrodes when each one of A, B, C, and
>   D are present

I propose:

*capacitance between a pair of electrodes when A, B, C, or D, respectively, is present*

OR

*capacitance between a pair of electrodes when one of the following is present: A, B, C, or D.*

Answer (score 0):

I'll elevate my old comment into an answer.  First, Rie Tanaka clarified his question in a comment as follows:

"Mr.Ab2, thank you for your comment. The capacitance depends on which one of the four is present between a pair of electrodes. For example, A is water, B is methanol, C is ethanol, and D is blood. A, B, C and D have different dieletric constances." – Rie Tanaka Sep 5 at 21:46

My comment was that Rie Tanaka has essentially answered his own question in his comment, and that my answer is:

*The capacitance between a pair of electrodes depends on which one of the four (A, B, C, or D) is present between the electrodes*